# help installing libpcap on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, libpcap

i was trying to install libpcap under cygwin on windows 7 but i had this error:
    $ ./configure
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    configure: error: see the INSTALL for more info

how can i solve this?
i am using libpcap-1.0.0 which is the latest version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is a late reply, but I just went through the same install issues on Windows 7.

On Windows, you should use Winpcap:   http://www.winpcap.org/

Comment: FYI - winpcap developer pack doesn't seem to work when using 64-bit cygwin. So if you still see pcap library missing error after putting the developer pack to the right location, try 32-bit cygwin

Answer (score 10):

http://mathieu.carbou.free.fr/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_install_Winpcap_/_Libpcap_under_Cygwin

libpcap develop pack can be found from 
http://www.winpcap.org/devel.htm

steps in detail as follows:

> ***Setup Winpcap***
>
> 1. Download and unzip the pack. We will use for this example WpdPack_4_0_1.zip.
> 2. Copy libraries like this:
>
>    - WpdPack\Lib\libpacket.a to cygwin\lib\
>    - WpdPack\Lib\libwpcap.a to cygwin\lib\
> 3. Create a folder cygwin\usr\include\pcap\
> 4. Copy all headers from WpdPack\Include to cygwin\usr\include\winpcap\
> 5. Be sure you have installed Winpcap libraries and that they are in your path by typing:
>
>    ```
>    which packet.dll
>    which wpcap.dll
>    ```
>
> For me they are in /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/
>
> ***Building example using Cygwin***
>
> Open a cygwin prompt to WpdPack\Examples-pcap\basic_dump\ and execute:
>
> *basic_dump:*
>
> ```
> CFLAGS="-g -Wall -mno-cygwin -I /usr/include/pcap"
> LIBS="-lwpcap"
> PROG="basic_dump"
> gcc $CFLAGS -c $PROG.c
> gcc $CFLAGS -o $PROG.exe $PROG.o $LIBS
> ./$PROG.exe
> ```
>
> *basic_dump_ex:*
>
> ```
> CFLAGS="-g -Wall -mno-cygwin -I /usr/include/pcap"
> LIBS="-lwpcap"
> PROG="basic_dump_ex"
> gcc $CFLAGS -c $PROG.c
> gcc $CFLAGS -o $PROG.exe $PROG.o $LIBS
> ./$PROG.exe
> ```
>
> *iflist:*
>
> ```
> CFLAGS="-g -Wall -mno-cygwin -I /usr/include/pcap"
> LIBS="-lwpcap"
> PROG="iflist"
> gcc $CFLAGS -c $PROG.c
> gcc $CFLAGS -o $PROG.exe $PROG.o $LIBS
> ./$PROG.exe
> ```
>
> *pcap_filter (and others):*
>
> ```
> I think you can catch the pattern ;) Only replace PROG=... by the program name and it should compile.
> ```
>
> *UDPdump:*
>
> ```
> CFLAGS="-g -Wall -mno-cygwin -I /usr/include/pcap"
> LIBS="-lwpcap -lwsock32"
> PROG="UDPdump"
> gcc $CFLAGS -c $PROG.c
> gcc $CFLAGS -o $PROG.exe $PROG.o $LIBS
> ./$PROG.exe
> ```
>
> You can test by doing a Time Synchronization with pool.ntp.org for
>   example.

Comment: Thank you, but I get an `unknown command line option  '-mno-cygwin'`. Followed all the steps, any advice?

Comment: @gies0r -mno-cygwin is obsoleted. You can remove this option and try again. FYI http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/g-mno-cygwin-flag-not-recognized-td134123.html

Comment: Thanks @camino. I think there is one more copy/paste issue here: `CFLAGS="-g -Wall -I /usr/include/winpcap/"` is needed because `CFLAGS="-g -Wall -I /usr/include/pcap/"` does not exists due to the extraction into  `\usr\include\winpcap\` in step 4. You could also simply change step 4 to extract into `/usr/include/pcap/`

Answer (score 5):

The libpcap source includes part, but *not* all, of the Windows support.  The mechanisms used to capture network traffic are very OS-dependent (which is why libpcap exists - to hide that detail from applications).

On UN*Xes, the mechanism is part of the OS, so libpcap doesn't have to provide that mechanism.

On Windows, there's no such mechanism in the OS, so WinPcap combines a kernel-mode driver, a low-level library that talks to the driver, and a module for libpcap that uses the low-level library.

The libpcap source doesn't include the driver or the low-level library, so it's not sufficient to build a version of libpcap for Windows.

As the other answers indicate, you need WinPcap.