# Errors when compiling a project with Cygwin

Tags: c++, windows, compilation, cygwin, winpcap

I'm trying to compile this project (https://github.com/alfchen/QoETrafficAnalyzer) in Windows 7 using Cygwin. In Linux I have no problem, but I need it in Windows. I installed winpcap following the steps included here: [help installing libpcap on cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396251/help-installing-libpcap-on-cygwin/15582855#15582855). However, I'm still having problems. I know the project uses arpa/inet.h and under windows you have to use winsock2.h, but changing that does not solve anything. Right now I'm having the following error. I hope someone can help me.

```
$ make
g++ -c tcpflowstat.cpp -Wno-deprecated -I include/ -o tcpflowstat.o
tcpflowstat.cpp: En la función miembro static ‘static int TCPFlowStat::isNewFlow(std::string, std::string, tcphdr*)’:
tcpflowstat.cpp:33:17: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘syn’
     if (tcphdr->syn==1 && tcphdr->ack!=1) return 1;
                 ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:33:35: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘ack’
     if (tcphdr->syn==1 && tcphdr->ack!=1) return 1;
                                   ^
tcpflowstat.cpp: En la función miembro ‘int TCPFlowStat::isMyPacket(std::string, std::string, tcphdr*)’:
tcpflowstat.cpp:39:31: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘source’
           && cltport==tcphdr->source && svrport==tcphdr->dest) \
                               ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:39:58: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘dest’
           && cltport==tcphdr->source && svrport==tcphdr->dest) \
                                                          ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:42:31: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘dest’
           && cltport==tcphdr->dest && svrport==tcphdr->source)) return 0;
                               ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:42:56: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘source’
           && cltport==tcphdr->dest && svrport==tcphdr->source)) return 0;
                                                        ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:43:59: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘source’
     int pktdir=getPacketDirection(ip_src, ip_dst, tcphdr->source, tcphdr->dest);
                                                           ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:43:75: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘dest’
     int pktdir=getPacketDirection(ip_src, ip_dst, tcphdr->source, tcphdr->dest);
                                                                           ^
tcpflowstat.cpp: En la función miembro ‘void TCPFlowStat::addPacket(std::string, std::string, int, tcphdr*, double, int, bool)’:
tcpflowstat.cpp:109:59: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘source’
     int pktdir=getPacketDirection(ip_src, ip_dst, tcphdr->source, tcphdr->dest);
                                                           ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:109:75: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘dest’
     int pktdir=getPacketDirection(ip_src, ip_dst, tcphdr->source, tcphdr->dest);
                                                                           ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:110:41: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘doff’
     int tcpdatalen=ippayloadlen-tcphdr->doff*4;
                                         ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:174:25: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘syn’
             if (tcphdr->syn==1 && tcphdr->ack!=1){
                         ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:174:43: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘ack’
             if (tcphdr->syn==1 && tcphdr->ack!=1){
                                           ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:178:33: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘source’
                 cltport=tcphdr->source;
                                 ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:179:33: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘dest’
                 svrport=tcphdr->dest;
                                 ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:180:32: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                 cltseq=tcphdr->seq;
                                ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:181:35: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                 svrackseq=tcphdr->seq+1; cltinitseq=tcphdr->seq+1;
                                   ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:181:61: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                 svrackseq=tcphdr->seq+1; cltinitseq=tcphdr->seq+1;
                                                             ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:192:25: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘syn’
             if (tcphdr->syn==1 && tcphdr->ack==1 && tcphdr->ack_seq==svrackseq){
                         ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:192:43: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘ack’
             if (tcphdr->syn==1 && tcphdr->ack==1 && tcphdr->ack_seq==svrackseq){
                                           ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:192:61: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘ack_seq’
             if (tcphdr->syn==1 && tcphdr->ack==1 && tcphdr->ack_seq==svrackseq){
                                                             ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:195:32: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                 svrseq=tcphdr->seq;
                                ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:196:35: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                 cltackseq=tcphdr->seq+1; svrinitseq=tcphdr->seq+1;
                                   ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:196:61: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                 cltackseq=tcphdr->seq+1; svrinitseq=tcphdr->seq+1;
                                                             ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:197:32: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘ack_seq’
                 cltseq=tcphdr->ack_seq;
                                ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:202:30: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘syn’
             else if (tcphdr->syn==1 && tcphdr->ack!=1 && pktdir==PKTSENDER_SVR){
                              ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:202:48: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘ack’
             else if (tcphdr->syn==1 && tcphdr->ack!=1 && pktdir==PKTSENDER_SVR){
                                                ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:205:32: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                 svrseq=tcphdr->seq;
                                ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:206:35: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                 cltackseq=tcphdr->seq+1; svrinitseq=tcphdr->seq+1;
                                   ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:206:61: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                 cltackseq=tcphdr->seq+1; svrinitseq=tcphdr->seq+1;
                                                             ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:211:30: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘fin’
             else if (tcphdr->fin==1 || tcphdr->rst==1){
                              ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:211:48: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘rst’
             else if (tcphdr->fin==1 || tcphdr->rst==1){
                                                ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:220:25: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘syn’
             if (tcphdr->syn!=1 &&tcphdr->ack==1 && tcphdr->seq==cltseq && tcphdr->ack_seq==cltackseq){
                         ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:220:42: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘ack’
             if (tcphdr->syn!=1 &&tcphdr->ack==1 && tcphdr->seq==cltseq && tcphdr->ack_seq==cltackseq){
                                          ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:220:60: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
             if (tcphdr->syn!=1 &&tcphdr->ack==1 && tcphdr->seq==cltseq && tcphdr->ack_seq==cltackseq){
                                                            ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:220:83: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘ack_seq’
             if (tcphdr->syn!=1 &&tcphdr->ack==1 && tcphdr->seq==cltseq && tcphdr->ack_seq==cltackseq){
                                                                                   ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:231:67: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘source’
                 pktdir=getPacketDirection(ip_src, ip_dst, tcphdr->source, tcphdr->dest);
                                                                   ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:231:83: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘dest’
                 pktdir=getPacketDirection(ip_src, ip_dst, tcphdr->source, tcphdr->dest);
                                                                                   ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:234:36: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                     cltseq=tcphdr->seq+tcpdatalen;
                                    ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:235:39: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘ack_seq’
                     cltackseq=tcphdr->ack_seq;
                                       ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:236:36: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘ack_seq’
                     svrseq=tcphdr->ack_seq;
                                    ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:239:36: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                     svrseq=tcphdr->seq+tcpdatalen;
                                    ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:240:39: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘ack_seq’
                     svrackseq=tcphdr->ack_seq;
                                       ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:241:36: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘ack_seq’
                     cltseq=tcphdr->ack_seq;
                                    ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:248:25: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘syn’
             if (tcphdr->syn==1 && tcphdr->ack==1 && simulsyn==1){
                         ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:248:43: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘ack’
             if (tcphdr->syn==1 && tcphdr->ack==1 && simulsyn==1){
                                           ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:250:54: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                 if (pktdir==PKTSENDER_CLT && tcphdr->seq==cltseq && tcphdr->ack_seq==cltackseq){
                                                      ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:250:77: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘ack_seq’
                 if (pktdir==PKTSENDER_CLT && tcphdr->seq==cltseq && tcphdr->ack_seq==cltackseq){
                                                                             ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:257:54: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                 if (pktdir==PKTSENDER_SVR && tcphdr->seq==svrseq && tcphdr->ack_seq==svrackseq){
                                                      ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:257:77: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘ack_seq’
                 if (pktdir==PKTSENDER_SVR && tcphdr->seq==svrseq && tcphdr->ack_seq==svrackseq){
                                                                             ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:277:25: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘syn’
             if (tcphdr->syn!=1) {
                         ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:280:33: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                     if (tcphdr->seq > cltseq){
                                 ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:284:33: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                     if (tcphdr->seq < cltseq){
                                 ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:286:50: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                         int retxb=cltseq-tcphdr->seq;
                                                  ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:296:33: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                     if (tcphdr->seq+tcpdatalen > cltseq) {
                                 ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:297:40: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                         cltseq=tcphdr->seq+tcpdatalen;
                                        ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:300:33: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘ack_seq’
                     if (tcphdr->ack_seq >= cltackseq) {
                                 ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:301:43: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘ack_seq’
                         cltackseq=tcphdr->ack_seq;
                                           ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:309:33: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                     if (tcphdr->seq > svrseq){
                                 ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:313:33: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                     if (tcphdr->seq < svrseq) {
                                 ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:314:50: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                         int retxb=svrseq-tcphdr->seq;
                                                  ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:325:33: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                     if (tcphdr->seq+tcpdatalen > svrseq) {
                                 ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:326:40: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘seq’
                         svrseq=tcphdr->seq+tcpdatalen;
                                        ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:330:33: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘ack_seq’
                     if (tcphdr->ack_seq >= svrackseq) {
                                 ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:331:43: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘ack_seq’
                         svrackseq=tcphdr->ack_seq;
                                           ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:337:29: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘fin’
                 if (tcphdr->fin==1 || tcphdr->rst==1){
                             ^
tcpflowstat.cpp:337:47: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘rst’
                 if (tcphdr->fin==1 || tcphdr->rst==1){
                                               ^
make: *** [Makefile:25: tcpflowstat.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Which fields does `struct tcphdr` contain? Some OSs define a bit field others use `#defines`.

Comment: @Jonas: Actually, I don't find the files where the struct is defined. Is it supposed to be in a header file?

Comment: I'm not familiar with windows, so I don't know which header to include. You can define it your self, examples at http://www.binarytides.com/raw-sockets-packets-with-winpcap/

Answer (score 0):

On cygwin the structure is defined on `/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h`
Its contents is:

```
struct tcphdr {
        u_int16_t th_sport;             /* source port */
        u_int16_t th_dport;             /* destination port */
        tcp_seq   th_seq;               /* sequence number */
        tcp_seq   th_ack;               /* acknowledgement number */
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
        unsigned int  th_x2:4,          /* (unused) */
                      th_off:4;         /* data offset */
#endif
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
        unsigned int  th_off:4,         /* data offset */
                      th_x2:4;          /* (unused) */
#endif
        u_int8_t  th_flags;
#define TH_FIN  0x01
#define TH_SYN  0x02
#define TH_RST  0x04
#define TH_PUSH 0x08
#define TH_ACK  0x10
#define TH_URG  0x20
#define TH_FLAGS (TH_FIN|TH_SYN|TH_RST|TH_ACK|TH_URG)

        u_int16_t th_win;                 /* window */
        u_int16_t th_sum;                 /* checksum */
        u_int16_t th_urp;                 /* urgent pointer */
};
```

Be aware that most of cygwin internal is taken from BSD and not from Linux
and in this case the two structures do not match.

Comment: I tried changing the code as it is defined in the struct on /usr/include/netinet/tcp.h but it doesn't work. Will I be able to compile it with cygwin if the program was originally made for linux? I mean, there are so many things that are very dependant to the operative system (sockets), I don't know if what I'm trying to do is even possible.